Reducing the minimum width of QLineEdit to three characters?
Using the example code below, I get four QLineEdit text fields/boxes, that stretch when I resize the main window horizontally, which I like:

However, when I shrink the window, I cannot reduce its width below this:

... probably because of some limit on minimum width of the line edits/text fields, which I find too large, as the text fields should contain at most 3 characters. However, if I try to print minimumWidth() of the text field, I get 0; so I cannot really reduce it.
So how can I have a line edit which otherwise stretches, but has a minimum Width that amounts to about the width of 3 (numeric) characters in the current font metrics?
Example code:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLineEdit

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.setWindowTitle("My App")

    vlay = QVBoxLayout()
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    self.le1 = QLineEdit("192")
    self.le2 = QLineEdit("168")
    self.le3 = QLineEdit("1")
    self.le4 = QLineEdit("1")
    print(f"{self.le1.minimumWidth()=}")

    hbox.addWidget(self.le1)
    hbox.addWidget(self.le2)
    hbox.addWidget(self.le3)
    hbox.addWidget(self.le4)

    vlay.addLayout(hbox)

    centralWidget = QWidget()
    centralWidget.setLayout(vlay)
    self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()


You can achieve what you want by subclassing QLineEdit, and overwriting the minimumSizeHint virtual method, to return something like QSize(0, default_height).

If you don't want to create a subclass, you can also get away with it by setting the minimum width to 1. Ex: self.le1.setMinimumWidth(1).

The only problem with this solution is that the widget will clip the text out, because it will shrink its width past to zero. You could get away with this by setting the font-size to a known size, and setting the minimum width to a fixed value. But, well... it's not a dynamic solution.

Also note that the minimum width should always be based on the font and possible input, not using arbitrary values. It also seems that you're using those line edits for numbers, so you should consider using QSpinBox instead.

The QSpinBox class automatically adjusts to a minimum size determined by several factors such as the font, the caret size, the number of digits of the maximum value, etc. So if the fields only require numbers, that would appear to be the simplest solution. (And it also has the side-benefit of providing input validation and a more convenient interface for the user).
